# What is the thinking behind the naming of arachidonic acid?

Tags: lipids, etymology

[Arachidonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachidonic_acid), the double bonded fatty acid, is occasionally [misrepresented](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHuu28diC_I) as having to do with spiders (arachnids). The Wikipedia entry explains that it's instead elated to "arachis" = peanut in New Latin. Alas, [peanut oil does not contain any of it](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0140673694916950?token=951134D5C9B3858FD5B7E10A53088FCA8F2B8CF4FD8A583C336052C128307305933A64C55293A8B3264728801236516C&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20230509124720). Bizarre! What went through the mind of the person who named this lipid and caused all the confusion and mispronunciation by learners? Is there any good reason for the name?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a problem in biology, but about the trivial name given to a compound over 100 years ago. It is little more than a rant, disguised as a question, the answer which can not possibly be known "what went through the mind…".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are finitely many letters and possible combinations of them making words, and many many things to be named. Inevitably, some of the words will be similar or even [homonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym). To me, having some really limited and basic knowledge of Latin and (Ancient) Greek, there is no real confusion here. All terms related to spiders have a different stem containing an **n**, namely *arach**n**ophobia arach**n**ologist, Arach**n**ida* ...

Regarding the naming, it was suggested in 1913<sup>1</sup> based on its similarity to [*arachidic* acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachidic_acid), which is indeed a (minor) constituent of peanut oil.

---

<sup>1</sup> Martin, S. A. *et al*. [The discovery and early structural studies of arachidonic acid](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4918860/). J Lipid Res. *2016*

Comment: Thanks Domen. That's just the paper I was looking for. I'm citing here to document the answer for readers here: "The name, arachidonic, was suggested in 1913 based on its relationship to the well-known arachidic acid (C20:0). It took until 1940 before the positions of the four double bonds were defined at 5,8,11,14 of the 20-carbon chain." [Arachidic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arachidic_acid) seems to a minor constituent of peanut oil at around 1%.